# Flutter save the selected item from a dropdownmenu into a variable

Tags: flutter

i want to save my selected item form a dropdown menu into a variable, that i can use my selection in an other file to show it there in a dialog box.
Is there a simple way how i can save the selection in a var or someone knew a better way to get my selection into the other file?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';

var AderOutput;

class Ader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AderState createState() => _AderState();
}

class _AderState extends State<Ader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: DropdownSearch<String>(
        validator: (v) => v == null ? "Erforderliches Feld" : null,
        hint: "Wähle eine Ader",
        mode: Mode.MENU,
        showSelectedItem: true,
        items: ["Ader 1", "Ader 2"],
        label: "Wähle eine Ader",
        showClearButton: true,
        onChanged: print,
        popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
        selectedItem: null,
        onBeforeChange: (a, b) {
          if (b == null) {
            AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Sind Sie sicher,'),
              content: Text('dass Sie die Auswahl zurücksetzten möchten?'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Ja"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  },
                ),
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Nein"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
            return showDialog<bool>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return alert;
                });
          }
          return Future.value(true);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It highly depends on what you wanna do in the other file. So what's your intention?

Comment: After i select my item in the dropdownlist i switch to a qrcode scanner with a button. Than i want to scan a Qrcode. When the code is scanned i want a pop up window on which the information from my Code and the selected information from my step before is written.